# Command-line tool to copy image from file into clipboard along with DPI information

Tags: windows, images, image-processing, command-line

I need a tool launched from the command line (or API) with an argument like "D:\image1.png" which copies the image into the clipboard including its DPI resolution.

Requirements:

- Windows
- up to 20€ (preferably free)
- **not** written in .NET (.NET clipbaord access methods cannot copy image DPI into clipboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Irfan View.](http://www.irfanview.com/)

It is an image viewer, but it has rich offer of command-line options which allow to perform actions *without opening* the user interface.

For copying the file into the clipboard, the command is:

```
i_view32.exe "D:\image1.png" /clipcopy /killmesoftly
```

And yes, it copies DPI resolution correctly into the clipboard along with the image.

IrfanView is  [freeware – but only for private, non-commercial use (that means at home).](http://www.irfanview.com/eula.htm)